# SQL query using WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

This might be simple but I'm new to SQL and couldn't find how to do this exactly.

and I have following table:

[image: Existing table in SQL]

My requirement is follows:

I need, for every Dim, for each Frequency, I need latest Date & maximum Version of that latest Date.
For example: There will be one row for Dim 'A' & Frequency 'Monthly' with their latest Date & the latest date's maximum Version. and There will be another row for Dim 'A' & Frequency 'Weekly' with their latest Date & the latest date's maximum Version.

Can anybody please help me with this?

I tried using following query but it not returning correct values:

```
SELECT Dim, Frequency, Date, Version
               FROM   sample_tbl 
               WHERE  ( Frequency, Date, 
                        Version ) IN ( 
select Frequency, max(Date), max(Version)
from sample_tbl
group by 1
);
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I'm using Postgres

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Postgres - return maximum value for latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023183/sql-postgres-return-maximum-value-for-latest-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Postgres, I think `distinct on` does what you want:

```
select distinct on (dim, frequency) s.*
from sample_tbl s
order by dim, frequency, date desc, version desc;
```

For each `dim`/`frequency` combination this returns one row.  That row is the first row encountered based on the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.

Is there way where I can get the latest Date for 'monthly' & latest Date for 'weekly' frequencies and pick all rows for Dim  where Date & Frequency are whatever we got in earlier?

Comment: @ParikshitShinge . . . Ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.